# I'm noticing a lack of questions related to systemic functional linguistics. Is this an accidental gap?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Just my own curiosity, mainly.

I'm noticing a lack (an absolute lack) of questions related to systemic functional linguistics, and I'm wondering whether this is because there just hasn't been any questions related to it asked, or whether it's intentional and/or out of scope for this site. It *seems* to be on-topic.

Thoughts?

Comment: It's on-topic here.

Comment: @prash Cool. I was just wondering. Maybe should've jumped in chat.

Comment: @jimsug No, asking on Meta whether a question is on topic is the right course of action. Chat is fine too, but posting here makes it better accessible for others that might want to ask something similar to you. :)

Comment: Whose variety of SFL are you asking about? It's not exactly monolithic, but rather overlaps with a great deal of cognitive linguistics, and the terminologies and focusses vary, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can ask about it. Just make sure the question fits the other guidelines (not too broad, clear, etc), otherwise you're good to go.

Marking this [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). :)